# Dependency Injection Container and Collections

Tags: php, dependency-injection, collections, containers

I have been searching for an answer in this topic but I haven’t been able to find a satisfactory one like in other topics, where the consensus is solid.

***The situation***

To keep things simple: I am implementing a custom Dependency Injection Container into one of my current projects (I know, I should use an already built one, but I’m doing it with learning purposes; so answers like ‘use this func of that container…’ are not useful) and I’ve stumbled a problem with instantiation of new elements inside a collection.

**The problem**

Imagine that I have a complex object, for example a car. This car has several dependencies (engine, axis, seats, airbags…) that have, at the same time, their own dependencies, and so on.
It is not a big issue to make the DiC (via autowiring or using a config file) build the object graph and inject all the dependencies with a simple line of code like:

```
$car = $container->get(‘car’);
```

The problem arrives when I build a CarCollection, which is a simple class that wraps an array of cars. The issue comes when I try to use a method that populates the collection with all the cars that exist in the database. It’s obvios that the collection should be able to create the Car objects on the fly when we call the “getAll” method from the database.
The code would be something like this:

```
public function populate(array $filters) {
    $all_data = $this->dao->getAll($filters); // Call the data access object to query all cars.
    foreach($all_data as $data) {
        $new_object = $this->container(‘car’); // create a template object
        $new_object->setData($data); // set the info.
        $this->items[] = $new_object; // Add to the collection.
     }
}
```

If car was not such a complex object it would be easier, because I could pass the car fqcn as a parameter for carCollection and use it in every iteration. But that’s not possible for a very complex object (or if I want to instantiate different sub types of the object - for example: lorry, pick-up, van…- depending on information from the database).

***The question.***

Regarding the collection being aware about the container: does not it break the purpose  of the DIC phylosophy?

I guess not on one side, because I am using PSR\Container to type hint the container I pass to the collection (which loosens the coupling). But it breaks the idea that the container should not be coupled with the domain model at all.

The only alternative that I have thought about is substituting the creation of one new object for each iteration with a cloning from a prototype object that lives in the collection as a property. But we all know cloning in php can get really tricky and very difficult to debug (Or worse: very difficult to even know  that there is a problem going on).

**Similar issue.**

PS: I have the same problem when I try to do lazy loading using Porxy objects: I need the proxy objects to have access to the container if I want to instantiate the full object later, which also  breaks the principles of a DiC.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

I think the core of your issue comes down to this:

> The issue comes when I try to use a method that populates the collection with all the cars that exist in the database.

The composition of object graphs of application components should be independent of any I/O, as described [here](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/) and [here](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/04/Composeobjectgraphswithconfidence/) by Mark Seemann. This means that the structure of those object graphs can't (and shouldn't) change based on changes in your database.

It seems to me that your `Car` object is a Domain Object, rather than a (Domain) Service. It would, therefore, be better suited to return a collection of `Car` instances from a service, rather than injecting the collection directly into one of your application components.

> I need the proxy objects to have access to the container if I want to instantiate the full object later, which also breaks the principles of a DiC.

It's generally considered to be a bad practice to let application code depend on the DI Container. This a a pattern known as the [Service Locator anti-pattern](https://freecontent.manning.com/the-service-locator-anti-pattern/). There are many reasons why Service Locator is considered to be a bad idea, but it's important to understand that the list of downsides of Service Locator do not apply when the DI Container is used in the application's startup path (a.k.a. the [Composition Root](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/)). A DI Container used within the Composition Root, is *not* an implementation of the Service Locator anti-pattern.

When your proxy classes are defined *within* the Composition Root, it's perfectly fine to let them depend on the DI Container and you won't violate any software principle or practice.

Comment: So If I understand you well, I should let the Class Car instantiate the collection and return it (populating it using for example the 'static' reserved word for every new car instance) ?  This would not be a suitable option because the car class has a set of dependencies (Then the Car class would be coupled with N classes instead of 1 (the conatiner) 
Regarding the proxy object, I guess you mean that it's okey for the proxy object to be aware of the DIC (having a property refereced to it) ??

Comment: I guess the alternative would be a factory pattern injected in one of the properties of the collection (so it's able to generate the objects on the fly). But then I see no reason why it's a better option than letting the container build something that he already knows how to build

Comment: There are many possible solutions, but you should prevent initializing your application components (classes that contain application *behavior*) with runtime data -and- you should prevent initializing runtime data object (such as Domain Objects that you pull in from the database) with application components. You can pass both in through methods on already initialized objects though. This might mean restructuring your code to some degree.

Comment: Thank you for the response Steven. But I am not able to wrap my head around the idea your trying to tell me. How am I suposed to present a list of all the details of the cars and some of its dependencies if I can't build them based on the information of the db? (We are talking about a request-based app, by the way).

Comment: It seems to me that `Car` shouldn't be resolved from your DI Container. It seems more a data object which deserves its own dao. But it might be useful to update your question and show some real code (assuming that "car" is just an illustrative concept that doesn't reflect your real domain).

Comment: Car is just a simplification of my domain objects, because I am looking for a conceptual solution for the problem. Because I'm trying to find a pattern to build collections of objects for one of my projects (Usually the collections will be of machines and all the dependant components). I can't give a sample because there's no sample. 

But conceptually it would go just like this: a machine has a set of properties, some of them are objects. One of them is a DAO that interacts with the DB (At the same time every dependecy have its own DAO). 
I do think that to build a single ...(next comment)

Comment: ... machine object, The DiC is a great option (otherwise I really don't see the point of a DiC). The problem is when I try to think about a way to instantiate a list of machines on the fly dependenfing on the filters some user applies.
I know you are saying that it is a bad idea (I have read some stuff saying the same), but anybody offers an alternative. And that's what this question is about. 

Sorry if I am missing something.